# How can I take screenshot from my APP in SmartTV

Tags: screenshot, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I want to take screenshots from my APP in a Smart TV (Samsung OS and Tizen).
I need the screenshots for my APP documentation and for submission process.

Does anyone know how can I take the screenshots or if it is possible? I cannot take in the emulator, because my videos use DRM and it is not compatible with the emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can debug the app on IDE, when the web inspector shows up, select "rendering debug". There is a screen capture option there.